# I want to make RadioButton ListItems ReadOnly without changing the appearance of control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here if i give Enable="False" property then the appearance turns grey from black... I do not want to change appearance... What to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this Property, (with d at the end)

```
Enabled="False"
```

Comment: Thanks... i did the same but cause of this control's background color turns grey from black color... so i do't want to change appearance.